# suspend doesn't work after upgrading to Debian 7.8

Tags: debian, suspend

On 2 partitions of my HD I have installed Debian 7.7 and Debian 7.8 (upgraded from 7.7).  The first OS has "suspend" to ram or disk working, the latter not anymore.
I made some tests, changing home and etc directories, without success.  It seems that after restore, the HD is working, but the OS not (it's freezed?).  The screen is black and the keyboard doesn't respond.  CTRL ALT F1, CapsLock, NumLock don't work.
s2ram and s2disk don't work too.
I did think that it was related to some file in /etc/X11 directory or in /home, that's why I copied those from the working OS to the other.
Can someone tell me what file suspend depends on? I could copy the right one from Debian 7.7 to 7.8.
I cannot believe that a so small problem forces a user to reinstall Debian. What the difference from Windows?
Thanks to all who will spend some time to resolve this very common issue.

EDIT: I have KDE, GNOME, LXDE.  The problem persists if I change Desktop Environment.

**EDIT** After upgrading the kernel to 3.2.65-1+deb7u1 suspend works but not hibernate. I installed uswsusp package and now hibernate works.
Thanks to all helping me to solve this annoying bug.

Comment: Any chance your init system got changed from SysV to systemd?

Comment: @peterph  How can I check this?

Comment: `ps fu -p 1` will give you description of process with PID = 1, which is the init system. For SysV init it should be `init` or someting similar, for systemd `systemd`.

Comment: @peterph  Thank you.  The output shows "init [2]":  root         1  0.5  0.0  10652   808 ?        Ss   15:15   0:00 init [2]

Comment: Next time please do add any additional info into the question (use the `edit` link below the post) - comments are not well suited for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a [known regression with suspend](http://bugs.debian.org/774436) in the current kernel of Debian 7.8. See [this blog entry](http://womble.decadent.org.uk/blog/linux-suspendresume-regression-in-debian-78.html) for more information and links.

Comment: I'm going to update the kernel as described in the link you posted.  I'll tell you.  Thanks.

Comment: OK suspend to ram now works, but not hibernate.  But there is a new problem: I cannot update with "apt-get update": ftp.it.debian.org is unreachable.  My LXDE panel shows an icon saying: "a package manager is beeng executed" (probably because ftp.it.debian.org is unreachable).  Internet works.

Comment: @user2431763 Replace ftp.it.debian.org with http://http.debian.net/ See its homepage for details.

Comment: @user2431763 It would helpful if you write a short mail to 774436@bugs.debian.org describing that suspend works for you with the test kernel, but not hibernation. Include some details about your PC.